# 'relationshipFilter' in apoc.path.expandConfig() doesn't seem to work

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a simple Neo4J DB, with 6 nodes and the following relationships:

`(n0:A {my_id:1})-[:A]->(n1)`
`(n1)-[:B]->(n2)`
`(n2)-[:C]->(n3)`
`(n3)-[:B]->(n4)`
`(n4)-[:A]->(n5:A)`

Running the following apoc query **returns nothing**:

```
match(n {my_id:1})
 with (n)
  call apoc.path.expandConfig(n,{relationshipFilter: "A|B|C",
       labelFilter: "/A", 
       uniqueness: 'RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL', 
       minLevel:1, maxLevel: 20, 
       filterStartNode:false}) yield path as path
return path
```

While running the following apoc query **returns path from n0 to n5**:

```
match(n {my_id:1})
 with (n)
  call apoc.path.expandConfig(n,{relationshipFilter: "",
       labelFilter: "/A", 
       uniqueness: 'RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL', 
       minLevel:1, maxLevel: 20, 
       filterStartNode:false}) yield path as path
return path
```

**The only difference is with relationshipFilter**.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: I created the nodes are relationships specified, and your first query provided the path of all the nodes as expected. You may want to double-check your graph first, as your query looks good to me. Also, what version of Neo4j and APOC are you using? If there is a bug here, knowing the version you're using should help find it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Neo 3.2.0, APOC 3.2.0.3